# OLAP, Dundas, C#.Net: Is there any sites to learn easily and quickly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, olap

Are there any sites to learn OLAP and Dundas easily and quickly?

Anywhere can I also see the source code. Like how the controls are interacting with db and how the Dundas charting controls are customized in backgroung code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but here's where I'd start if I was new to both concepts:

OLAP tutorial:  http://training.inet.com/OLAP/home.htm
 and this: http://www.learndatamodeling.com/olap_analysis.htm

Dundas: http://www.dundas.com/Dashboard/Start/Tutorials/index.aspx

If you provide more details, you may get more specific results/direction.

Hope this helps!

Comment: anywhere can I see the source code, like how the controls are talking to db and how the dundas charting controls are customized in code behind?